Running docker compose for golang app with postgres database
I have created a Dockerfile for a golang back-end app and a docker-compose.yml where I have the the app and Postgres database as services. I can successfully build and run the Dockerfile using docker build -t command and docker run command. But when I try to run the docker-compose.yml file using docker-compose up --build command, it can't seem to find the executable (.exe) file which should be in the working directory(WORKDIR).

Dockerfile

FROM golang:1.22-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

COPY .env .env

RUN go build -o bin ./cmd

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/app/bin"] 



docker-compose.yml

version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:.
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DSN=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/tutor-connect
      - PORT=${PORT}
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/vendor
    env_file:
      - .env

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: tutor-connect
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:



Error When running docker-compose up build:

exec /app/bin: no such file or directory
tutor-backend-app-1 exited with code 1

I have tried changing the build property of app service in docker-compose.yml file to image and giving it the build image from the Dockerfile but it does not work and the following error persists:
exec /app/bin: no such file or directory

You mounted the current directory as /app in the image launched from docker-compose, so the binary is no longer under /app/bin
